# Show Java code editor in DDMS perspective

Tags: eclipse, ddms, perspective

In "Java" perspective I can see Java code (between "Package Explorer" and "Outline" - depends on your settings, however it's a kind of default I think).

Then I add "DDMS" perspective and I can't see Java code. I have only "Devices" and "Threads", "Heap" etc. No Java editor in between.

**How to show Java code in DDMS perspective?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply switch the editor by setting up a keyboard shortcut to really toggle the editor area visibility. Open the Preferences and navigate to **General > Keys** **(or press Ctrl/Cmd + Shift + L )** twice to jump right to the Keys preferences).

Search the commands for area and then assign a keyboard shortcut to the Toggle Editor Area Visibility command.